# semi_join and anti_join functions creating dtplyr objects instead of data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, dtplyr

So I'm working on a project which requires me to combine dataframes with semi_join and anti_join from dplyr. However, instead of creating a data.frame as output, I get a dtplyr_step_subset object which I am unable to use and I have no idea how it works. (Note that this only happened after I updated my tidyverse package) Is there some argument for the join functions that fixes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know for certain without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But my best guess is that it is probably using `semi_join` from `dtplyr`, which gives you a `data.table`. In general to avoid overlapping functions from different packages, I recommend specifying the package for functions. So, you would use `dplyr::semi_join()` and `dplyr::anti_join()`. Also, if you don't need `dtplyr` then you can always detach it via `detach("package:dtplyr", unload=TRUE)`.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that the problem was having the dtplyr package loaded. After unloading it everything worked as I'd expected it to?